# Woocommerce simple product is not visible

Tags: woocommerce

I created a simple product via WooCommerce but is not showing when I click it after publishing.

Please, if anyone could answer my question that'd be of great help.

Comment: Do you have any template overrides for products? Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: We can't debug your site for you. But you can try disabling you other plugins, and reverting to a default theme to help yourself identify the source of the problem.

Comment: i am using a plugin for managing menus , does that effect product view ?

Comment: @Aibrean no i am not facing any template overrides issue .